# Pandoc and Word export: Change DPI of images

Tags: docx, pandoc, dpi

I want images in my Pandoc exported Word docx files to be scaled a little.

By default, an image can be around 640px of width at 72dpi so it is exported by Pandoc to the full width of my reference docx (which means: it isn't scaled down by Pandoc to make it fit the space).

I'd like all my images to look a little bit crispier when printing the document (or zooming on screen). I'd like all of them to be scaled down visually by 1/4th or 1/3th (staying at the same resolution).

I played around with `--dpi` option of Pandoc and set it to 300 (by default it's 96), which didn't have an effect on the size of the images.

I also tried to set the dpi of my images using Photoshop, which simply resulted in bigger images, but they were also displayed bigger when exported using Pandoc (regardless of the `--dpi` option).

The only way which had the desired effect was to set an explicit width in Markdown:

```
![my image](image.jpg){ width=2cm }
```

But this needs a lot of calculation on my side to get the desired value, because using `{ width=50% }` makes the image have half of the width of the surrounding container. Not what I need.

I think I misunderstand something general about this topic. Maybe somebody can explain me a bit.

Comment: I think unless you specify a width or height, the [docx writer scales](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.hs#L1194) the image to the page width if its too large... the dpi option only kicks in to convert cm to px or vice versa, e.g. `![my image](image.jpg){width=2cm}` to HTML where it will be 75px...

Comment: So you mean I have to reside to manual calculations and set a `width`?